# Pager in one control, view in a different control?

Tags: xpages

I have a situation where I need to place a pager in one control and the view for that pager in a different control.  I have the native pagers for the view turned off.

If I place a page in the same control as the viewer then it works fine but if I place the pager in one control and the view in another control and place them both on the same page, I get the error *Pager is not associated with any data control.*  Any idea of how to accomplish this?  Maybe I need to specify the control id that has the view along with the view associated with the pager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can associate pager with view panel manually using 'Attach to' property on pager (or just simply add/change tag 'for' into source which represent property 'Attach to'.

```
<xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="footerPager"
id="pager2" for="viewPanel1" >
```

Comment: This worked great thanks.   It is pretty much what I tried but did not work for me.   Your code worked perfect when I threw together a demo but when I went to use my CC containing the view it did not work.  I had to completely rebuild the view pretty much like I had it but when I did it, it worked too.  Not sure what was wrong.  Thanks again.